# Unexpected "-1H" appearing in MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim

If I run `:!ls` inside MacVim, I get an odd "-1H" control character appearing when I type enter.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: bad control character appearing]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Yosemite, Vim version 7.4.258, not sure which version of MacVim.

Comment: Custom Version 7.4 (73)

Comment: Do you experience the same problem in vim itself (run in the Terminal)?

Comment: No and to be honest, I can't reproduce it anymore in MacVim (though I could a week ago). I don't know why or what changed. Probably need to close this issue.

Comment: unfortunately I can't close it now because of the bounty. sorry :(

Comment: @KevinBurke you might have luck flagging for moderator attention and asking them to close it as no longer reproducible, You must mention that is a bountied question. (Otherwise can you post your vimrc)

Comment: Possibly you are suffering from a bad keyboard mapping. Backspace and delete are likely suspects. This would explain why you are not getting this all the time; your typing `:!ls` might involve the occasional use of backspace. See if you can reproduce the problem by typing a few characters too many and deleting them again. Or use any other control keys you may have pressed.